# IBM MobileFirst V8.0 : update active user

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm using MobileFirst Platform V8.0 and I need to update the active user attributes after a successful login. Is there any solution to update the active user without logout.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to Logout to set the active user & You can set active user in adapter soon after user is authenticated by using API `setActiveUser`.

Details about `setActiveUser` and `getActiveUser` API's can be found [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/api-ref/mfp-server-java-apidoc/html/refjava-mfp-server/html/com/ibm/mfp/server/security/external/checks/AuthorizationContext.html#setActiveUser(com.ibm.mfp.server.registration.external.model.AuthenticatedUser)).

Following code is an example on how to do it in adapter for Mobilefirst 8.0 Enrollment [Sample](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/enrollment/).

```
public void authorize(Set<String> scope, Map<String, Object> credentials, HttpServletRequest request, AuthorizationResponse response) {
    PersistentAttributes attributes = registrationContext.getRegisteredProtectedAttributes();
    if (attributes.get("pinCode") != null){
        // Is there a user currently active?
        if (!userLogin.isLoggedIn()){
            // If not, set one here.
            authorizationContext.setActiveUser(userLogin.getRegisteredUser());
        }
        setState(SUCCESS_STATE);
        response.addSuccess(scope, getExpiresAt(), this.getName());
    } else  {
        setState(STATE_EXPIRED);
        Map <String, Object> failure = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        failure.put("failure", "User is not enrolled");
        response.addFailure(getName(), failure);
    }
}
```

For more information please go through [this tutorial](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/enrollment/).